# User does not have access to target (s3) from Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to access an s3 bucket in different AWS account using Athena, but I'm getting the below error message :

> User does not have access to target.

I have added all the necessary policies to the s3 bucket in the other AWS account.
When I add the s3 location as a datastore in my account, I am unable to crawl the bucket which is located in the other account.

Is there anything that I need to do from my side in terms on policy.

Comment: Please take a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/ and here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cross-account-permissions.html

Comment: Two parts are necessary: (1) The IAM User in the AWS Account using Athena (Account-A) must be given permission to access the bucket in the different account (Account-B), and (2) A bucket policy is required on the S3 bucket in the 'other' account (Account-B) that grants access permission for the IAM user from Account-A.